# How Can I Make Text Animation Effect, Hello World to HW in JavaScript or CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, animation

How Can I Make Text Animation Effect, Hello World to HW in JavaScript or CSS?

First Text is Hello World!
At last, become HW, with disapearing other letters.

Hello World!

↓

Hell World!

↓

He Wld!

↓

HW

Comment: you can do it use only css. wrap each letter in `span` and add css animation to each `span`

Comment: Investigate animation and steps, give it a go and if you are still stuck put your code so far into your question with a description of what isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5Sop.gif)

```js
<script>
export default {
    name:"Introduction",
    data() {
        return {
            timer:1,
        }
    },

    mounted() {
      this.deathLoop = null
      this.deathLoop = setInterval(()=>{
        this.timer+=1
        if(this.timer>4) this.timer=1
      },1000)
    },
}
</script>
```

```css
<style scoped>
.Introduction{
    padding-top: 60px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 20px;
}
span{
    font-size: 30px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;

}
</style>
```

```html
<template>
  <div class="Introduction">
     <span >H</span>
     <span v-show="timer<4">e</span>
     <span v-show="timer<3">l</span>
     <span v-show="timer<3">l</span>
     <span v-show="timer<2">o</span>
     <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
     <span >W</span>
     <span v-show="timer<3">o</span>
     <span v-show="timer<3">r</span>
     <span v-show="timer<4">l</span>
     <span v-show="timer<4">d</span>
     <span v-show="timer<4">!</span>
  </div>
</template>
```

Check the image.
Maybe it's what you want. Code by Vue.js2 and you can copy it in pure Javascript

Comment: You should consider using `requestAnimationFrame` if you wanna create an animation with JavaScript. Besides that the logic is correct, even if I'd use a transition over `max-width` and `opacitiy` in order to make the animation smoother

Comment: Moreover, OP didn't ask for Vue :)

Comment: Oh, thank you. The GIF is what I want. What is the keyword for search like that effect? I'm not really good at English.

Comment: I don't know about this either, this effect may not have a definite name, but you can write one yourself :)